# ios 5 - exctracting sounds

Tags: ringtones, audio

Is there a possiblity to get / exctract alert and ringtone sounds (sound files) from iOS 5?

I was also trying to find them elsewhere on the internet, but without any luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) can access pretty much any file on any iOS device, it doesn't matter what version of iOS you are running.

1...Launch PhoneView and go to preferences and make sure that (Show entire disk (Advanced Disk Mode), is checked).

[image: Preferences]

2...In the window to your left select "Disk" Then go to Library -> Ringtones. This is where the ringtones are stored.

3...For the alert sounds go to System -> Library -> Audio -> UISounds. This is where all of the alert sounds are stored.

If you have custom made or downloaded any ringtones in iTunes or other programs, you can find them in the window to your left under Ringtones.

Comment: Thanks, are there any good Windows alternatives?

Comment: [TouchCopy](http://www.wideanglesoftware.com/touchcopy/index.php)  Looks like it is the windows alternative.